# Removing bytes in a dump or utf-8 in c

Tags: c

I have a "C" program in my firestation that captures incoming packets to the station printer.  The program then scans the packet and sends and audible alert for what apparatus is due on the call.  The county recently started using UTF-8 packets and the c program can not deal with all the extra "00" in the data flow.  I need to either ignore the 00 or set the program to handle UTF-8.  I have looked for days and there is nothing concrete on how to handle utf-8 that a novice such as my self can handle.  Below is the interpret part of the program.

*72 00 65 00 61 00 74 00  68 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00*  later in packet

*43 4f 44 45 53 45 54 3d  55 54 46 38 0a 40 50 4a*  beginning of packet

```
***void compressUtf16 (char *buff, size_t count) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    buff[i] = buff[i*2];     // for xx 00 xx 00 xx 00 ...
```

}***
{   u_int i=0;
    char *searcher = 0;
    char c;
    int j;
    int locflag;
    static int locationtripped = 0;

```
    static char currentline[256]; 
static int currentlinepos = 0;
static char lastdispatched[256];
static char dispatchstring[256];

char betastring[256];

static int a = 0;
static int e = 0;
static int pe = 0; 
static int md = 0;

static int pulse = 0;

static char location[128];
static char type[16];
static char station[16]; 

static FILE *fp;
static int printoutscanning = 0;
static char printoutID[20];
static char printoutfileID[32];

static FILE *dbg;

if(pulse) {
    if(pulse == 80) {
        sprintf(betastring, "beta a a a");
        printf("betastring: \"%s\"\n", betastring);
        system(betastring);
        pulse = 0; 
    } else
        pulse++;
}

    if(header->len > 96) {
        for(i=55; (i < header->caplen + 1 ) ; i++) {
            c = pkt_data[i-1];

        if(c == 13 || c == 10) {
            currentline[currentlinepos] = 0;
            currentlinepos = 0;
            j = strlen(currentline);
            if(j && (j > 1)) { 
                if(strlen(printoutfileID) && printoutscanning) {
                    dbg = fopen(printoutfileID, "a");
                    fprintf(dbg, "%s\n", currentline); 
                    fclose(dbg);
                }

                if(!printoutscanning) {
                    searcher = 0;
                    searcher = strstr(currentline, "INCIDENT HISTORY DETAIL:"); 
                    if(searcher) {
                        searcher = searcher + 26;
                        strncpy(printoutID, searcher, 9);
                        printoutID[9] = 0;
                        printoutscanning = 1; 
                        a = 0;
                 e = 0;
                        pe = 0;
                        md = 0;
            for(j = 0; j < 128; j++)
                            location[j] = 0; 
                        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                            type[j] = 0;
                            station[j] = 0;
                        }
                        sprintf(printoutfileID, "calls/%s %.6d.txt", printoutID, header-> ts.tv_usec);
                        dbg = fopen(printoutfileID, "a");
                        fprintf(dbg, "%s\n", currentline);
                        fclose(dbg);
                    }
```

Comment: utf-8 won't give you zeros, you probably mean utf-16?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't use 00 as a special encoding character.  Are you sure you don't have UTF-16?

Comment: A "C" program?  Is its status as C questionable?

Comment: my apologies didnt want any confusion

Comment: It looks much worse. It is mixed UTF-8 and UTF-16 (or UCS-2). You have to parse and split input first.

Comment: @ninjalj It could be UTF-16BE too. It is from the middle of the data stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8, except for the zero code point itself, will not have any zero bytes in it. The first byte of all multi-byte encodings (non-ASCII code points) will always start with the `11` bit pattern, with subsequent bytes always starting with the `10` bit pattern.

As you can see from the following table, `U+0000` is the only code point that can give you a zero byte in UTF-8.

```
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Unicode        | Byte 1   | Byte 2   | Byte 3   | Byte 4   |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| U+0000-007F    | 0xxxxxxx |          |          |          |
| U+0080-07FF    | 110yyyxx | 10xxxxxx |          |          |
| U+0800-FFFF    | 1110yyyy | 10yyyyxx | 10xxxxxx |          |
| U+10000-10FFFF | 11110zzz | 10zzyyyy | 10yyyyxx | 10xxxxxx |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

UTF-16 will intersperse zero bytes between your otherwise ASCII bytes but it's then a simple matter of throwing away every second byte. Whether that's `0, 2, 4, ...` or `1, 3, 5, ...` depends on whether your UTF-16 encoding is big-endian or little-endian.

---

I see from your sample that your data stream *does* indicate UTF-8 (`43 4f 44 45 53 45 54 3d 55 54 46 38` translates to the text `CODESET=UTF8`) but I'll guarantee you it's lying :-)

The segment `72 00 65 00 61 00 74 00 68 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00` is UTF-16 for `reathing`, presumably a word segment since I'm not familiar with that word (in English, anyway).

I would suggest you clarify with whoever is generating that data since it's clearly erroneous. As to how you process the UTF-16, I've covered that above. Provided it's ASCII data in there (the alternate bytes are always zero), you can just throw away those alternates with something like:

```
// Process a UTF16 buffer containing ASCII-only characters.
// buff is the buffer, count is the quantity of UTF-16 chars.
// Will change buffer.

void compressUtf16 (char *buff, size_t count) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        buff[i] = buff[i*2];     // for xx 00 xx 00 xx 00 ...
}
```

And, if you're using the *other* endian UTF-16, simply change:

```
buff[i] = buff[i*2];     // for xx 00 xx 00 xx 00 ...
```

into:

```
buff[i] = buff[i*2+1];   // for 00 xx 00 xx 00 xx ...
```

Comment: The begining of the packet is easily interpreted and clearly says UTF-8 so thats what Im basing my info on.  I can post the dump if that will help.

Comment: @PGFDBUG, yes, that would help. However, it may _claim_ to be UTF8 but, unless you actually _have_ zero code points in your input stream, there's no way to get a zero byte.

Comment: @PGFDBUG: Yes, it would help.  Be sure to anonymize it if necessary.

Comment: @PGDBFUG: What's the specification of the data format? Perhaps there's a run of length-prefixed UTF16 at the back?

Comment: please forgive me im in way over my head.  Where can I find how to throw away the extra bytes

Comment: I guess 'reathing' is the tail end of 'breathing', a plausible word in a message to (or from) a paramedic at a fire station.

Comment: I added the code above I believe that is the right place if not I will find out soon enough.  Thank you for all your help you have given me plenty to work with and some guidance to move forward